# Making repetitive if/else or case statements more DRY

Tags: ruby, if-statement, case, dry

I often find myself with if/else statements that are essentially the same line repeated while comparing to a different value. Here I'm writing code to the predict the amount of deaths from a deadly influenza outbreak. It has been refactored into a case statement, that still is very WET:

```
  def predicted_deaths(population_density, population, state)
    case
      when population_density >= 200 then number_of_deaths = (population * 0.4).floor
      when population_density >= 150 then number_of_deaths = (population * 0.3).floor
      when population_density >= 100 then number_of_deaths = (population * 0.2).floor
      when population_density >= 50 then number_of_deaths = (population * 0.1).floor
      else number_of_deaths = (population * 0.05).floor
    end
    ap "#{state} will lose #{number_of_deaths} people in this outbreak"
  end
```

I tried getting something to work with

```
j = 0.4
i = 200
  until i <= 50 do
    @population_density >= i then number_of_deaths = (@population * j).floor
    i -= 50
    j -= 0.1
  end
```

But that doesn't really do the same thing.

How can I make the repetitive case statement more DRY?

**EDIT**

Two suggestions here that seem like two very different but equally good refactors:

For readability's sake:

```
def predicted_deaths(population_density, population, state)
  factor = case population_density
    when 0...50 then 0.05
    when 50...100 then 0.1
    when 100...150 then 0.2
    when 150...200 then 0.3
    else 0.4
   end
  number_of_deaths = (population * factor).floor
  ap "#{state} will lose #{number_of_deaths} people in this outbreak"
end
```

more condensed but less readable:

```
def predicted_deaths(population_density, population, state)
  number_of_deaths = (population * 0.05).floor
  for i in 1..4
    number_of_deaths = (0.1 * i * population).floor if population_density.between?(50*i, 50*(i+1)) || population_density >= 200
  end
  ap "#{state} will lose #{number_of_deaths} people in this outbreak"
end
```

Comment: It's a small thing, but I don't think the printing of the result within the method is good programming practice. It would be better to remove the `state` argument and return the number of deaths, which would then be printed outside the method. That way, if you later needed number of deaths elsewhere in your code, you wouldn't have to change the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to shorten your case statement:

```
def predicted_deaths(population_density, population, state)
  factor = case population_density
    when 0...50 then 0.05
    when 50...100 then 0.1
    when 100...150 then 0.2
    when 150...200 then 0.3
    else 0.4
   end
  number_of_deaths = (population * factor).floor
  ap "#{state} will lose #{number_of_deaths} people in this outbreak"
end
```

Comment: This would be my first refactoring step.

Comment: I believe the range queries are slightly off. For example, if the population density is 50, 100, 150, 200 then the factor will be 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 (respectively). For example: `(150..200).include?(200)` is `true` but `(150...200).include?(200)` is `false`.

Comment: @KevinSylvestre you are correct, I needed the non-inclusive range. Fixed.

Comment: @MarkThomas I think so. It will fail for negative population densities (probably not possible?) and will also fail for float population densities (never mind - thought it wouldn't match the edge but that was because I tested with the .. and changing the index). Again, while I like the look of this code, it isn't very robust in some sense.

Comment: (0...50).include? 49.5 #=> true

Comment: As you only need the upper end of each range, it might make sense to have them all start at zero,. That way, if you want to change a limit, you only need change a single number.

Comment: @Kevin, if this were production code, you would want to make all sorts of checks for bad data, but that's really a different question, and addressing that here, or in most other questions posted on SO, would just be a diversion. Your point about the treatment of range endpoints is valid, of course. Hey, I just noticed you're in Victoria. I'm in Cook St. Village.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah, very cool. I just moved out to Victoria. Haven't noticed a big tech scene in the area; any other Rubyists on the island?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, but I've made no effort look. Drop me an email. The address is on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this untested code:

```
def predicted_deaths(population_density, population, state)
  pct = case
        when population_density >= 200 
          0.4
        when population_density >= 150 
          0.3
        when population_density >= 100 
          0.2
        when population_density >= 50 
          0.1
        else
          0.05
        end

  ap "#{state} will lose #{ (population * pct).floor } people in this outbreak"
end
```

---

There are several steps I go through to refactor code like this, starting with looking for the repetitive parts and trying to move them down/out of the conditional tests (the `case` statement in this... uh... case).

Here's the first pass:

```
def predicted_deaths(population_density, population, state)
  number_of_deaths = case
                     when @population_density >= 200 
                       (@population * 0.4).floor
                     when @population_density >= 150 
                       (@population * 0.3).floor
                     when @population_density >= 100 
                       (@population * 0.2).floor
                     when @population_density >= 50 
                       (@population * 0.1).floor
                     else 
                       (@population * 0.05).floor
                     end
  ap "#{@state} will lose #{number_of_deaths} people in this outbreak"
end
```

At this point it's obvious that `@population *` and `floor` are redundant so I moved those down.

There are problems with your use of instance variables and local variables though. You reference `@population_density`, `@population` and `@state` but have local variables in the method's parameters which are being used to pass in the values. You can't do that. Remove the `@` to turn the variables into local variables.

Comment: Yeah about my reference to instance variables, sorry about that. I took this snippet of code from a larger instance with more methods, and it makes more sense in context. Perhaps I should remove the @'s in my post just for clarity?

Comment: Your code in the question *MUST* accurately reflect the code in your program. Otherwise, it defeats the purpose of asking a question here as we'll have no basis for accurate answers.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1) You can make the case statement use a single assignment:

```
state = case(city)
when "Miami" then "Florida"
when "Omaha" then "Nebraska"
...
end
```

2) You can make a helper function that encompasses the logic that isn't common (this will help show what isn't DRY):

```
def percentage_of_deaths_for_population_density(population_density)
  case
  when population_density >= 200 then 0.4
  when population_density >= 150 then 0.3
  when population_density >= 100 then 0.2
  when population_density >= 50 then 0.1
  else 0.05
end
```

Then you can rewrite the snippet as:

```
def predicted_deaths(population_density, population, state)
  number_of_deaths = (population * percentage_of_deaths_for_population_density(population_density)).floor
  ap "#{state} will lose #{number_of_deaths} people in this outbreak"
end
```

3) Finally if you care you can refactor the `percentage_of_deaths_for_population` further (but I think it is pretty readable and would probably leave it - this is really just if you have a huge statement):

```
def percentage_of_deaths_for_population(population)
  { 200 => 0.4, 150 => 0.3, 100 => 0.2, 50 => 0.1 }.each do |limit, ratio|
    return ratio if population >= limit
  end
  return 0.05
end
```

4) Don't use instance variables if you are passing in the same variables! Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def predicted_death(population_density, population, state)
      number_of_death = (@population * 0.05).floor
      for i in 1..4 
        number_of_death = (0.1 * i * @population).floor if @population_density.between?(50*i, 50*(i+1)) || @population_density >= 200
      end
      ap "#{@state} will lose #{number_of_deaths} people in this outbreak"
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can boil me in oil, but I'd use a hash instead of a `case` statement.

```
FACTORS_BY_DENSITY = { 200=>0.4, 150=>0.3, 100=>0.2, 50=>0.1, 0=>0.05 }

@data_by_state = {..., "Utah"=>{pop: 4_325_641, pop_density: 126 },...}

def predicted_deaths(state)
  state_data = @data_by_state[state]
  (state_data[:pop] * factor(state_data[:pop_density])).to_i
end

def factor(density)
  FACTORS_BY_DENSITY.find { |d,_| density >= d }.pop
end

state = "Utah"
deaths = predicted_deaths(state)
  #=> 865128 
puts "#{state} will lose #{deaths} people in this outbreak"
  # Utah will lose 865128 people in this outbreak
```